# HTC Desire - cannot turn Bluetooth on!

Tags: htc-desire, bluetooth

I was playing with Android Bluetooth API on HTC Desire. Bluetooth was working fine, then suddenly it stopped. Now I cannot turn it on, even manually from the Settings menu. Here is something from Logcat,

```
01-06 07:34:37.208: ERROR/bluedroid(96): bluetoothd stop timed out
01-06 07:34:47.215: ERROR/bluedroid(96): btld start timed out
01-06 07:34:47.215: ERROR/bluedroid(96): $#$#$#$#$# Stopping btld because of starting btld fail...
```

What should I do? Please help!! :(

Comment: Have you rebooted the phone?  The steps you took before this started happening might be useful information as well.

Comment: @Matthew Read: Yes, I have. I've also tried taking the battery off. No result. Last option would be resetting the phone, but I hope to avoid that. I was just trying to set the Bluetooth device name programmatically. I guess the characters were too long. Then this odd problem occurred.

Comment: Hmm, I'm assuming you can't set the name to something shorter without enabling Bluetooth first.  Probably it's just a config file somewhere and you can edit the name ... I'll take a look around my phone later.

Comment: @Matthew Read: You're right, all Bluetooth menus are disabled. Currently Device name says "No name set, using account name". Config file is a good idea. I hope Google will give a better result using this keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset the phone works. Only difference is that I have to set the device into discoverable mode each time I turn the Bluetooth on. It was automatically set before.